# Show the picture when the mouse comes on the span

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I want to show a picture in an information box when the mouse hovers over the span. There are multiple spans. How can I do that?

```css
.tooltip {
  position:relative; 
  border-bottom:1px dashed #000; 
}
.tooltip:before {
  content: attr(data-src); 
  position:absolute;


  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);


  left:100%;

  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:#000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;

  display:none; 
}
.tooltip:hover:before {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix product-variants-item col-xs-6">
      
      <span data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/No_ecb_mode_picture.png" class="control-label labelayarlari tooltip">First Select</span>
              <select
          class="form-control form-control-select"
          id="group_9"
          data-product-attribute="9"
          name="group[9]">
                      <br><br><br><option value="34" title="Yes" selected="selected">Yes</option>
                      <br><br><br><option value="33" title="No">No</option>
                  </select>
          </div>
      <div class="clearfix product-variants-item col-xs-6">
      <span class="control-label tooltip" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Icon_Photo.png">Second Select</span>

              <select
          class="form-control form-control-select"
          id="group_12"
          data-product-attribute="12"          
          name="group[12]">
                      <br><br><br><option value="48" title="No" selected="selected">No</option>
                      <br><br><br><option value="49" title="Yes">Yes</option>
                  </select>
          </div>
```

It only writes the links in the snippet. I want the photos to appear.
Note: The 2 pictures are different.

Answer (score 1):

To get the content of a before or after pseudo element to actually show an image rather than just show its URL it needs to have this sort of format:

```
content: url("http://www.example.com/test.png");
```

So start by putting the url and brackets as part of the data attribute to see if it then shows

```
<span data-src="url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/No_ecb_mode_picture.png)" class="control-label labelayarlari tooltip">First Select</span>
```

If you need more formatting of the image it sometimes helps to have it as a background image rather than content, but it depends on what you want the tooltip to look like.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of that can achieve this, first is some super specific css selection like

```css
span:hover + * + * + img {
    display: block
}
```

Second is (JS) binding a mouseenter and mouseleave event to the span, and then showing/hiding the image from there.